# dynamic height css in fluid grids

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic, height

I'm trying to dynamically change height according to width but it's not responding. I have javascript from this website:

My code is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>

        <style type="text/css">
        #OB{
            background:#C60;
            width:50%; 
            overflow: hidden;  
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="OB">OrangeBlock</div>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        script.src = 'http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js';

        var cw = $('#OB').width();
        $('#OB').css({
            'height': cw + '%'});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have javascript from this website: http://jsfiddle.net/n6DAu/1/

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you want the element to resize with the browser window?

Comment: How are you trying the height according to width? The code written here is just saying make it the width percent, so if it's 500, the height will be 500%.

Comment: Blazemonger: Yes, basically, the with of the window. You can see the website on: www.tomdabek.info, it's about the you tube videos that are streaching too much

Comment: Marc Marta: I'm going to use 16:9 ration for youtube video windows, so I'll most likely will use about 40% of the width.

Comment: wbsite: tomdabek.info

Answer (score 0):

ur not calling the function on resizing

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 var cw = $('#OB').width();
  $('#OB').css({
  'height': cw + '%'});
});
```

besides that u also will need to call it onload, total code would be

```
$(function() {

  var cw = $('#OB').width();
  $('#OB').css({
  'height': cw + '%'});

  $(window).resize(function() {
   var cw = $('#OB').width();
    $('#OB').css({
    'height': cw + '%'});
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't Repeat Yourself. Use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) instead.